# Natural isomorphism and direction of dual map

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was randomly asking a teacher why there is no natural isomorphism between a vector space $V$ and its dual $V^*$ while there was one between $V$ and its double dual $V^{**}$ He said that it's because the dual of a linear transformation go the other way? And so for the double dual once you flip back again, you're back to where you started.

Can someone explain this in a nice and clear way

Comment: Given a linear transformation $f : V \to W$, there is a "natural" way of getting a linear transformation $f^* : V^* \to W^*$, by defining $f^*(\phi) = \phi \circ f$ - that's the dual of the linear transformation. There is no "natural" way of using $f$ to define a linear transformation $V^* \to W^*$, without extra information: e.g., a choice of a basis for $V$ and $W$.

Comment: sorry it's not very clear. Why isn't it natural?